# On Android, Display.getInstance().openGallery() does not allow multiple selection

Tags: codenameone

The following code allows multiple image selection on iOS and the emulator. On Android the Gallery window opens but only one image can be selected - even if you long press. If you open Gallery manually (outside of the codenameone app) then multiple selection is available.

```
Display.getInstance().openGallery((e) -> {
    if(e != null && e.getSource() != null) {
        String[] files = (String[])e.getSource();

        String filenames = "";
        for (int i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
            filenames = filenames + files[i] + "|";
        }
        System.out.println("selected filenames:" + filenames);
    }
},  CN1Constants.GALLERY_ALL_MULTI);
```

A call to :

```
isGalleryTypeSupported(CN1Constants.GALLERY_ALL_MULTI)
```

returns true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of Androids intent system. When you pick from a gallery the first time around it should prompt you with an option to select the gallery app. Some gallery apps just don't support multi-selection.

You can clear the associations for the app from the system settings to trigger that prompt again. Then select a different application which will hopefully resolve that issue.

Unfortunately, due to the way Android works this is the only reasonable workaround.